Question regarding linear resolution of an ideal
Let $R=K[x_1,x_2,\ldots,x_n]$. $I(G_{(x)})$ is edge ideal of $G_{(x)}$. In the proof of theorem 2.13 given in paper uses the fact that $L=xI(G_{(x)})$ has linear resolution if and only if $I(G_{(x)})$ has linear resolution.
Definition of the graph $G_{(x)}$: Edge set of $G_{(x)}$ is defined as $E(G_{(x)})=\{\{u,v\}\in E(G): \{u,v\}\cap N(x)\neq\phi, u\neq x,v\neq x\}$ and $V(G_{(x)})=N(x)\cup \{y\in V(G): \{y,x_i\}\in E(G), x_i\in N(x), y\notin N(x)\}$.
My attempt to prove the fact:  
Suppose $I(G_{(x)})=(u_1,u_2,\ldots u_m)$ has linear resolution. Then by Theorem 10.2.6 in the book Herzog-Hibi's Monomial ideals, $I(G_{(x)})$ has linear quotients. $i.e,(u_1,u_2,\ldots u_{i-1}):u_i $ is generated by linear forms for all $i$. Then $J=xI(G_{(x)})$ is generated by $(xu_1,xu_2,\ldots xu_m)$.
$(xu_1,xu_2,\ldots xu_{i-1}):xu_i $ is generated by {${xu_j/gcd(xu_j,xu_i): j=1,2,...i-1}$} which is again generated by linear forms. $i.e, J$ has linear forms. Again by proposition 8.2.1 in the book of Herzog-Hibi, J has linear resolution.
But I'm stuck to proceed with converse. I would like to get help with this and thank you in advance.

The above trick holds in general, infact if $a$ is a homogenous nzd on $R$ of any degree $d$ say, then $I$ has linear resolution iff $aI$ has linear resolution by considering the isomorphism $$ I(-d) \xrightarrow{\mu_a}  aI$$
Which establishes equality among betti numbers upto a shifting, which proves our assertion.
NOTE: Another way to look at the result could be to look at the first syzygy, in which $a$ being a nzd goes away and thus all syzygies of $I$ and $aI$ agree.
